# Redirect to the source application post login is not happening

Tags: spring-boot, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to build an authorization server which can be used in our API server to authorize the users.

There are primarily two applications in my use case:

1. Spring boot authorization server: All my users are in mongodb and password encoder is  Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder
2. An API server with swagger enabled: Swagger tries to connect to authorization server via OAuth2 (implicit). API server validates the token using OIDC client.

Case 1: Now, I am able to login using the Default login form provided and I can see the user is authenticated in the logs.
Based on the logs it is redirected to the /?continue but there is no html pages configured to this URL and it is showing a Whitelabel Error Page

Case 2: Swagger application is configured for oauth2 implict. I am able to redirect to authorization server login page and able to authenticate the user. Authentication is successful based on the logs but the redirection back to the swagger UI is not happening.

Here is the logs I can see in the authorization server console:

```
2023-07-14T14:23:03.427-07:00 DEBUG 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /login
2023-07-14T14:23:03.427-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/14)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.427-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/14)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.427-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/14)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.427-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/14)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.427-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/14)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.427-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/14)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.428-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2023-07-14T14:23:03.428-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/14)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.428-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.428-07:00  INFO 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] .s.AuthorizationServerUserDetailsService : Found user for bwayne
2023-07-14T14:23:03.524-07:00 DEBUG 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-07-14T14:23:03.524-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/2)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.525-07:00 DEBUG 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] .s.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy : Changed session id from 4E0FDEB6B7AE5D9219E9CEAB38F8B550
2023-07-14T14:23:03.525-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with CsrfAuthenticationStrategy (2/2)
2023-07-14T14:23:03.525-07:00 DEBUG 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.s.w.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy  : Replaced CSRF Token
2023-07-14T14:23:03.526-07:00 DEBUG 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User{identifier=c52bf7db-db55-4f89-ac53-82b40e8c57c2, username='bwayne', password='{bcrypt}$2a$10$uWySuc0T2N90Tgx.y1yffOpBJUeGyL/coaap/0TLnqzkzLR4TcciS', firstName='Bruce', lastName='Wayne', email='bruce.wayne@example.com', roles=[USER]} com.example.spring.authorizationserver.user.User@668673a8, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=4E0FDEB6B7AE5D9219E9CEAB38F8B550], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1fd9654a]
2023-07-14T14:23:03.526-07:00 DEBUG 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User{identifier=c52bf7db-db55-4f89-ac53-82b40e8c57c2, username='bwayne', password='{bcrypt}$2a$10$uWySuc0T2N90Tgx.y1yffOpBJUeGyL/coaap/0TLnqzkzLR4TcciS', firstName='Bruce', lastName='Wayne', email='bruce.wayne@example.com', roles=[USER]} com.example.spring.authorizationserver.user.User@668673a8, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=4E0FDEB6B7AE5D9219E9CEAB38F8B550], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2023-07-14T14:23:03.526-07:00 DEBUG 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8081/error?response_type=token&client_id=ldc-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fswagger-ui%2Foauth2-redirect.html&state=RnJpIEp1bCAxNCAyMDIzIDE0OjIyOjQzIEdNVC0wNzAwIChQYWNpZmljIERheWxpZ2h0IFRpbWUp&nonce=fc73892d-dd18-4310-a1c2-e34873536d24&continue
2023-07-14T14:23:03.526-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-07-14T14:23:03.531-07:00 TRACE 67469 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest$H2ConsoleRequestMatcher@45daf7b0, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@150bedbc, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4d0af94a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@6f10fadb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2c73e15e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@42d0b735, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1e9550bb, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@14e2186c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6205aca4, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7ab6dc12, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@1518b324]] (1/3)
```

Here is the code snippet of Application config:

```
@Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> {
            User user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
            UserClaim userClaim = userClaimsRepository.findByUserId(user.getId())
              .orElseThrow(() ->
                new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("User doesn't have an entry in the claims repository"));
            user.setPassword(getHashedPassword(userClaim.getSalt(), userClaim.getHashedPassword()));
            return user;
        };
    }

    private String getHashedPassword(String salt, String hashedPassword) {
        byte[] saltBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(salt);
        byte[] cipherBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(hashedPassword);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(EncodingUtils.concatenate(saltBytes, cipherBytes));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder =
                new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder("", SALT_LENGTH, NO_OF_ITERATIONS, PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512);
        passwordEncoder.setEncodeHashAsBase64(true);
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

Application.yml file

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          client-1:
            registration:
              client-id: "admin-client"
              # the client secret is "secret" (without quotes)
              client-secret: "vfOhk8S1Rr1CSV6e89+Aw5HvkHoIhxH/dW6Wpcrutyv62xnOIaAJIliJKNN31L/NQlZqnqRAHcGS0hP8Nys4F3cNFcsJ02f/2FFArLYdXrs="
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "client_credentials"
                - "refresh_token"
                - "authorization_code"
              redirect-uris:
                - "http://localhost:8888/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html"
              scopes:
                - "openid"
            require-authorization-consent: true
```

Can someone please help what am I missing here?

Comment: Notice that you are being redirected to `/error`. Please share the earlier part of the logs where the error actually happens.